# Create Hive Table on Multiple CSV blobs of Azure Blob Storage

Tags: csv, azure, hadoop

I have a Azure Blob Storage. In a Container called DATA, I have CSV blobs in following way - 
[image]

Now I have created a Hadoop Cluster using HDInsight.

As the next part I wanted to create Hive Table for querying. Here I have specific questions.

**1) How to Load ALL BLOBS to a Hive Table in a single query?**

For single BLOB I can use something like following query. But how to do that for MULTIPLE Blobs in single query?

```
# Use the external table option. 
$queryString = "DROP TABLE log4jLogs;" +
                "CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE log4jLogs(t1 string, t2 string, t3 string, t4 string, t5 string, t6 string, t7 string) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ' STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION 'wasb://$containerName@$storageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/example/data/';" +
                "SELECT t4 AS sev, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM log4jLogs WHERE t4 = '[ERROR]' GROUP BY t4;"
```

2) What is the main difference between LOAD DATA and EXTERNAL TABLE while creating Hive Table?

Any inputs would be helpful.

**####################### UPDATE1 #####################**

I followed below suggestions, but not able to make it work for **ONE BLOB**.

My BLOB is CSV. I uploaded it through powershell form my local to blob storage. This blob storage and container got default samples of HDInsight. Blob data shown below.

- 1,Rami,Vemula,29
- 2,Jack,Aston,33

[image]

My Hive Query -

```
# Provide Windows Azure subscription name, and the Azure Storage account and container that is used for the default HDInsight file system.
$subscriptionName = "Rami"
$storageAccountName = "storagename"
$containerName = "containername"


# Provide HDInsight cluster name Where you want to run the Hive job
$clusterName = "clustername"


# Use the external table option. 
$queryString = "DROP TABLE mylogss;" +
                "CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE mylogss(t1 string, t2 string, t3 string, t4 string) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION 'wasb://$containerName@$storageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/blobrami/';" +
                "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM mylogss;"


# Create a Hive job definition 
$hiveJobDefinition = New-AzureHDInsightHiveJobDefinition -Query $queryString


# Submit the job to the cluster 
Select-AzureSubscription $subscriptionName
$hiveJob = Start-AzureHDInsightJob -Cluster $clusterName -JobDefinition $hiveJobDefinition



# Wait for the Hive job to complete
Wait-AzureHDInsightJob -Job $hiveJob -WaitTimeoutInSeconds 3600
```

Result - 
[image]

So finally I was not able to get any output.It exited with code 1. I am not sure what I did wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loading multiple CSV blobs into hive Table can be achieved in the following simple steps.

First we need to slightly change how data is being organized in our container. I have made following formatting with 'data/csv/filename'

[image]

Then we can use following hive query to load **all** the CSV blobs in one shot. There is non need for any iterations.

```
# Provide Windows Azure subscription name, and the Azure Storage account and container that is used for the default HDInsight file system.
$subscriptionName = "***"
$storageAccountName = "***"
$containerName = "***"
$clusterName = "***"


# Use the external table option. 
$queryString = "DROP TABLE logs;" +
               "CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE logs(t1 string) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION " + 
               "'wasb://$containerName@$storageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/data/csv';" 


# Create a Hive job definition 
$hiveJobDefinition = New-AzureHDInsightHiveJobDefinition -Query $queryString


# Submit the job to the cluster 
Select-AzureSubscription $subscriptionName
$hiveJob = Start-AzureHDInsightJob -Cluster $clusterName -JobDefinition $hiveJobDefinition


# Wait for the Hive job to complete
Wait-AzureHDInsightJob -Job $hiveJob -WaitTimeoutInSeconds 36000

# Get Output
Get-AzureHDInsightJobOutput -Cluster $clusterName -JobId $hiveJob.JobId -StandardOutput -StandardError
```

Answer (score 3):

An external table is a table for which hive manages metadata only (the schema, ...).
A regular hive table in which you load data has its metadata AND its data managed by HIVE.

If you drop an external table, you don't loose the data.

For HDInsight, I usually use external tables because I can keep adding data in blob storage (wasb) while the cluster is off (thus while I don't pay for it). When i restart a cluster against that data, I just have to run the hive script that creates the external tables to be able to access them thru hive. No data loading.

Here is a sample script:

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

create external table IF NOT EXISTS raw_tweets ( json_response string ) partitioned by (dt string) stored as textfile;
alter table raw_tweets add if not exists partition(dt='2013-03-06') location 'wasb://mycontainer@mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/data/socialvilles/2013-3-6';
alter table raw_tweets add if not exists partition(dt='2013-03-07') location 'wasb://mycontainer@mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/data/socialvilles/2013-3-7';
alter table raw_tweets add if not exists partition(dt='2013-03-08') location 'wasb://mycontainer@mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/data/socialvilles/2013-3-8';
alter table raw_tweets add if not exists partition(dt='2013-03-09') location 'wasb://mycontainer@mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/data/socialvilles/2013-3-9';
alter table raw_tweets add if not exists partition(dt='2013-03-10') location 'wasb://mycontainer@mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/data/socialvilles/2013-3-10';
alter table raw_tweets add if not exists partition(dt='2013-03-11') location 'wasb://mycontainer@mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/data/socialvilles/2013-3-11';
alter table raw_tweets add if not exists partition(dt='2013-03-12') location 'wasb://mycontainer@mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/data/socialvilles/2013-3-12';

create external table IF NOT EXISTS tweets2 (
    id string,
    lang string,
    json_response string)
partitioned by (dt string)
row format delimited fields terminated by '\t' lines terminated by '\n' stored as textfile 
location '/wasbwork/tweets2';

insert overwrite table tweets2
partition (dt)
select 
    get_json_object(json_response, '$.id_str') as id,
    get_json_object(json_response, '$.user.lang') as lang,
    json_response, 
    dt
    FROM raw_tweets
    where (length(json_response) > 500);
```

You can then remove you HDInsight cluster and find the result in your blob storage at yourdefaultblobstorage.blob.core.windows.net/yourclustercontainer/wasbwork/tweets2

If you want to use regular HIVE tables, I would recommand to create the HDInsight cluster with it Hive and Oozie metastore in Azure SQL Database (there's an option for that when you create the cluster), so that Hive remembers where it stored its data.

Comment: Hello benjguin, can you please look into the question update. I tried some of the code with my blob uploaded to storage. Unfortunately I was not able get any results.

Comment: you can get the output of your job in HDInsight with the following command: Get-AzureHDInsightJobOutput -JobId $hiveJob.JobId -StandardError -StandardOutput `
    -TaskSummary -Cluster $clusterName

Comment: You can also invoke Hive with PowerShell thru Invoke-AzureHDInsightHiveJob which will send you the results automatically. You can also RDP to the head node, store the HQL file to C:\1.hql for instance, then open the command prompt on the desktop, cd ..\hive<TAB KEY>\bin, hive -v -f c:\1.hql

Comment: Also have a look at you storage folder. For instance, I've already created an external table to (...)/somefolder/*.xxx which created a blob named *.xxx. Obviously, that was not what I was expecting and this generated errors afterwards.

Comment: Thanks @benjguin, I will give a try with all your suggestions and will get back to you.